# Business logic for identify SQL column update

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a SQL table called `contacts` which as `n` number of rows where n is more than 10Lakh (1 million) rows.

Below is the table structure with dummy data

```
+---------------+------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------------------+
|     email     | department |  title  |   state   | country | cleansing_verification |
+---------------+------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------------------+
| xyz@email.com | h.r.       | sr. Exe | telangana | Ind     |                      - |
+---------------+------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------------------+
```

So, I have 4 schedulers to cleanse the data which is present in the above table, ie

1. department cleanser
2. title cleanser
3. state cleanser
4. country cleanser

Each cleanser will update the data of the respective columns. I have added one more column call `cleansing_verification` to identify which column is updated but not able to use properly.

One email can be touched by any of the cleansers. Which means all 4 can update the value or any 3 or any 2 or only 1.

So, the problem is I'm facing is How to identify which email is touched and which is not so that for remaining I can send an email notification.

If something more need let me know I will add in the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the "cleansers" run an update, why don't they update the `cleansing_verification` column as well?

Comment: they can update the column ```cleansing_verification``` but what value needs to update?

Comment: You say you wanted to write the updated columns into it. So why don't you do it? The code that performs the update will surely know which columns it is updating.

Answer (score 1):

So normally we don't do this in the world of database design, but you could use bitfields. So your `cleansing_verification` is a `BIT(4)` type column, and each cleanser gets a bit they can set:

- department = `B'1000'`
- title = `B'0100'`
- state = `B'0010'`
- country = `B'0001'`

When running i.e. state, you would then:

```
UPDATE contacts 
   SET cleansing_verification = cleansing_verification | B'0010'
 WHERE -- whatever conditions you want to apply
```

If you wanted to check which rows were updated by a given cleanser, you check if the bit is set, e.g. for state:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE cleansing_verification & B'0010' = B'0010'
```

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7b22c67e53df0819830553f52f1513d8)

Actually proper way to do it would be to introduce a new table with a foreign key back to the `contacts` table and a column for a cleanser, like (quick'n'dirty example):

```
CREATE TABLE contacts_verification
(
   contact_id int references contacts(id),
   cleanser int
)
```

Then if you want to mark a record you just insert the contact id and some sort of cleanser identification (1, 2, 3, 4), or you can use a text field and meaningful names if you really want:

```
INSERT INTO contacts_verification (contact_id, cleanser) VALUES (21386, 1)
```

Then just use `JOIN` to get back the records marked by a cleanser:

```
SELECT c.*
  FORM contacts c
  JOIN contacts_verification dep_verify
    ON dep_verify.contact_id = c.id
   AND dep_verify.cleanser = 1
```

Comment: seems the right approach. But if a single email is touched by department and state then what value I can update in that particular column. As it has a very large amount data so a separate table will be a bit harder to process. Is there any other except DB. I can opt that as well.

Comment: Normally you'd insert a row per (contact, cleanser), so you'd have two rows (one for dept, one for state). If you're concerned about large amounts of data, you can use the bitfield approach I described.